# Java array list loop and return of String[] of select pairs of elements

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need to write a method that loops through `ArrayList<String>` pathClientStatic and then copies certain elements to a `String[]`.

pathClientStatic is an `ArrayList` containing a string of timestamp x y

Each is seperated by a space " ", and there will always be a tuple though the number of tuples varies with how long the path is. So there may be timestamp x y timestamp x y timestamp x y or simply timestamp x y.

If there is more than a pair of tuples in the `ArrayList`, ie timestamp x y timestamp x y what I want is to copy x y x y of the final pair of tuples in the array, so the very last x y and the penultimate x y, out and into the `String[]`. At the moment I have the code below;

```
    public static String[] returnLastFour()
    {
    String data = "";
    int pathSize = pathClientStatic.size();
    if (pathSize > 6)
    {
        data += pathClientStatic.get(pathClientStatic.size()-5) + " ";
        data += pathClientStatic.get(pathClientStatic.size()-4) + " ";
        data += pathClientStatic.get(pathClientStatic.size()-2) + " ";
        data += pathClientStatic.get(pathClientStatic.size()-1);
    }
    else 
    {
        data += "nothing";
    }
    data.trim();
    String[] lastFour = data.split(" ");
    return lastFour;
    }
```

Though for some reason it doesn't always pull out the last two x y pairs. For example when the `ArrayList` contains;

**15:29:20.841 137.0 137.0 15:29:20.841 137.0 137.0 15:29:20.841 28.0 45.0**

What I want the `String[]` to end with is;

**137.0 137.0 28.0 45.0**

But instead I get;

**137.0 137.0 137.0 45.0**

I imagine it's just an obvious mistake but I have been staring/playing with this code for so long I just see a haze now.

Help appreciated.

Comment: There is no need to put them on a String and then split, you can just create the String before and add each element to it directly. Also, reuse pathSize inside each get.

Comment: @Argote I don't understand what/how you mean create the string before? I will change it to use pathSize, that I can see. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant the String array which you return, create it before calling the `get` methods and assign the results of each `get` directly to the output String array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks correct to me. Are you absolutely certain of your inputs?

PS -- It's best to use StringBuilder instead of `data += ...`

**Edit**

Now I'm positive: you'll get `137.0  137.0 28.0 45.0` if you run this program on the input you listed. Check the code that populates your original array.

Comment: Out of curiosity (I didn't know that) why is it better to use `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Performance, every time you modify a String a new Object is created.

Comment: @Tom Marthenal: Argote is right. The more full explanation I give at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941429/design-guidelines-for-heavy-string-operations/4941467#4941467 is for .NET, but strings work the same way in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the help all, have changed and basically optimized the code now and have basically determined the error is elsewhere, either where I initially store the path or where I return the path. Typical, thanks again, really appreciated.